# window.onbeforeunload not firing in Layout.cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Layout.cshtml:

```
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            alert("navigating away");
        };
```

Not firing, can you help?

Comment: I assume it is surrounded by <script type="text/javascript">...</script> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not `alert` anythnig inside the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) function. You should return a string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "navigating away";
    };
</script>
```

The way this string will be presented to the user is user agent dependent. You have absolutely no control over it. But in most cases it will appear as a confirmation popup.

Comment: Thanks Darin. and one more question: can I execute function in this event without alerting anything. for example by placing return null; ?

Comment: No, you can't. This function is reserved only to prompt the user whether he wants or not to navigate away from your site. Before returning this string you could indeed call some custom function of yours. But you should always return a string.

Comment: Is there alternative way to do this without returning a string?

Comment: @karaxuna, alternative way to do what? You haven't even explained what you are trying to achieve and you are asking me if there are alternative ways?

Comment: I said that I want to call javascript function when navigating from page without alerting anything

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand. You can't do that with `onbeforeunload`. You could try using the [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) event instead.

Comment: What did you put in the `onunload` function? Did you put an alert? Google Chrome blocks alerts in those functions. If you put some other function call without alerting anything it will work.

Comment: I don't know about other fields, but in mvc you are genius :)

Comment: Well, your question here has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. I don't even know why you tagged it so. This is pure javascript.

Comment: ok, ok, then you are web genius :D Well, I'm not experienced in web development and I thought that maybe because mvc has different structure it might be reason why my code did not work. I understand that everything is rendered and browser reads all it as html and javascript, but... Don't judge me, I don't have deep understanding of web, I'm learning :)

Answer (score 1):

As Darin mentioned you can **only** return a string.

When onbeforeunload is called, it will take the return value of the handler as window.event.returnValue and then parse the return value as a string (unless it is null)
False is parsed as a string, the dialogue box will fire, which will then pass an appropriate true/false.

There is no way of assigning false to onbeforeunload.